# Game Maker build Android application failed null returned: 1

Tags: android, proguard, game-maker

I try to create an Android application with Game Maker: Studio but I keep getting the following error:

```
release:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] Found 1 AIDL files.
     [aidl] Compiling 1 AIDL files.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Temp\gm_ttt_59755\gm_ttt_2511\res\values\strings.xml:29: error: Found text " ${YYAndroidStringValues}
     [aapt] " where item tag is expected

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Carl\Documents\Programs\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Carl\Documents\Programs\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:698: null returned: 1
```

I have the newest version of the Android APK. The only thing that's on line 698 is `proguardFile="${out.absolute.dir}/proguard.txt">` (which is a file I can't find at all on my computer).
Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here.

The problem is in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Do this test:

1. Open your AndroidManifest.xml
2. Paste the code above. It's a clean and valid Android Manifest file.

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
   <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="helloWorld" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
       <application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
           <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="HelloWorld" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
           </activity>
       </application>
       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
   </manifest>
   ```
3. And change "package="helloWorld" to name of your package.

Try build. If the build success, your AndroidManifest have some invalid instruction and you need to verify one by one.

In my case, i found the error in `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.White.NoTitleBar"` instruction. I change to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"` and it works.